# How to load image from parse to UIImage into a UITableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimageview

I can't load the image from parse. The thumbs called "question" it's ok, but when I try load the image from parse, an error happens and the app crashes

Take a look:

```
import UIKit
class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {

// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {

        super.init(style: style, className: className)

    }

    required init!(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

// Configure the PFQueryTableView

self.parseClassName = "Saude"

        self.textKey = "Nome"

self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true

self.paginationEnabled = false

    }

//    Define the query that will provide the data for the table view

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

        let query = PFQuery(className: "Saude")

        query.orderByAscending("Nome")

        return query

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()



// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell") as! CustomTableViewCell!

        if cell == nil

        {

            cell = CustomTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")

        }

        if let nome = object?["Nome"] as? String

        {

            cell.customNome.text = nome

        }

        if let categoria = object?["Categoria"] as? String

        {

            cell.customCategoria.text = categoria

        }

        let initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")

        cell.customImage.image = initialThumbnail

        if let thumbnail = object?["imageFile"] as? PFFile

        {

            cell.customImage.file = thumbnail

            cell.customImage.loadInBackground()

        }

     return cell

    }





// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].

//*let detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

let detailScene : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewControlleras! DetailViewController

// Pass the selected object to the destination view controller.

iflet indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            let row = Int(indexPath.row)

            detailScene.currentObject = (objects?[row] as! PFObject)

        }

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

// Refresh the table to ensure any data changes are displayed

        tableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```

**Error:**

```
2015-10-23 11:12:25.457 GuiaMogiNav[958:306603] -[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176ce9a0

2015-10-23 11:12:25.459 GuiaMogiNav[958:306603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176ce9a0'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x243bd85b 0x35d32dff 0x243c3025 0x243c0c7f 0x242f01a8 0xf13fc 0xf1810 0x189017 0x28830d63 0x28830e89 0x28820df5 0x2883546f 0x285db5af 0x284edcc3 0x27db5b05 0x27db1201 0x27db1091 0x27db05b1 0x27db0263 0x27da9a1f 0x24380091 0x2437e387 0x2437e7c5 0x242d10d9 0x242d0ecd 0x2d646af9 0x2855a2dd 0xe435c 0x36480873)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

(lldb)
```

Comment: please show just the part that is relevant to your problem. In order to help you

Comment: I don't know where is the problem. I'm trying to load a picture into a image in a tableview. But it don't works when I trying do this from parse. The image just don't load from parse. (Sorry about my english. I'm Brazilian and my english is no good

Comment: Falo português, mas não é permitido aqui. Okay I am trying to check your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is cell.customImage a PFImageView?

The UIImageView does not have the property file, but the PFImageView has it, and you should use it to load parse images.

And if you are using Storyboard, you need to change the class of the customImage object to PFImageView in the identity inspector.